# initialising useState with data is not refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, frontend, react-hooks

I have a route:

```
<Route path="/projects/:handle" component={Project} />
```

When I browse to i.e. `/projects/my-project-1`, the page loads successfully, however, if I go to `/projects/my-other-project`, the content of the page remains the same (my-project-1 content).

the `match.params.handle` acquired by the component changes, but useState still retains the (my-project-1) data.

```
const Project = ({ match }) => {

   const projectContext = useContext(ProjectContext)
   const [project] = useState(projectContext.getProject(match.params.handle))

   // my-other-project
   console.log(match.params.handle);

   let proj = projectContext.getProject(match.params.handle);

   // returns my-other-project
   console.log(proj)

   const [project] = useState(proj)

   // this is still my-project-1 data
   console.log(project);

   return (
       <>
        <Row>
            <Col sm={12} lg={12}>
                <ProjectOverview projectContext={projectContext} project={project} />
            </Col>
        </Row>
    </>
   );
}

export default Project;
```

What may I be doing wrong with the way I'm loading my component data and is there a better way, perhaps via useEffect? (I'm *somewhat* new to react (and react hooks))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That isn't how you use props to initialize state (we'll come back to that in a minute).

In general, there's no reason to copy props to state. Just use the prop. That's what it's for. It's basically state for your component that's managed by the parent component. So:

```
const Project = ({ match }) => {

    const projectContext = useContext(ProjectContext)
    const project = projectContext.getProject(match.params.handle); // ***

    return (
        <>
            <Row>
                <Col sm={12} lg={12}>
                    <ProjectOverview projectContext={projectContext} project={project} />
                </Col>
            </Row>
        </>
    );
}
```

*(Side note: There's no need for that fragment, you can return the `Row` directly.)*

If `projectContext.getProject(match.params.handle)` is an expensive operation, you can memoize it via [`useMemo`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo):

```
const Project = ({ match }) => {

    const projectContext = useContext(ProjectContext)
    const project = useMemo(
        () => projectContext.getProject(match.params.handle),
        [match.params.handle]
    );

    return (
        <>
            <Row>
                <Col sm={12} lg={12}>
                    <ProjectOverview projectContext={projectContext} project={project} />
                </Col>
            </Row>
        </>
    );
}
```

Live Example:

```js
const { useState, useEffect, useMemo, useContext } = React;

const Row = props => <div {...props}/>;
const Col = props => <div {...props}/>;
const ProjectOverview = ({projectContext, project}) => {
    return <div>Project: {project.name}</div>;
};

const contextValue = {
    getProject(handle) {
        console.log(`Getting project ${handle}...`);
        // busy-wait half a second
        const end = Date.now() + 500;
        while (Date.now < end) {
            // Wait -- NEVER BUSY WAIT LIKE THIS IN REAL CODE
        }
        return {name: `Project for handle ${handle}`};
    }
};
const ProjectContext = React.createContext(contextValue);

const Project = ({ match }) => {
    console.log(`Project called with handle = ${match.params.handle}`);

    const projectContext = useContext(ProjectContext)
    const project = useMemo(
        () => {
            console.log(`Recalcuating project from handle ${match.params.handle}`);
            return projectContext.getProject(match.params.handle);
        },
        [match.params.handle]
    );

    console.log(`project is: "${project.name}"`);
   
    // Note: Can't use <>...</> in Stack Snippets, we have
    // to use the older React.Fragment syntax.
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <Row>
                <Col sm={12} lg={12}>
                    <ProjectOverview projectContext={projectContext} project={project} />
                </Col>
            </Row>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}

const App = () => {
    const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
    const [handle, setHandle] = useState(1);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        if (handle < 3) {
            setTimeout(() => {
                setCounter(c => {
                    c = c == 0 ? 1 : 0;
                    if (c == 0) {
                        // Update the handle every two calls
                        setHandle(h => h + 1);
                    }
                    return c;
                });
            }, 800);
        }
    }, [handle, counter]);

    return (
        <ProjectContext.Provider value={contextValue}>
            <Project match={{params: {handle}}} />
        </ProjectContext.Provider>
    );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.12.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Notice how `getProject` was only called when the handle changed, not every time the `Project` component function was called.

---

**If** you need to use props to initialize state, [here's what the React docs have to say about it](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-do-i-implement-getderivedstatefromprops):

> **How do I implement `getDerivedStateFromProps`?**
>
> While you probably don’t need it, in rare cases that you do (such as implementing a `<Transition>` component), you can update the state right during rendering. React will re-run the component with updated state immediately after exiting the first render so it wouldn’t be expensive.
>
> Here, we store the previous value of the row prop in a state variable so that we can compare:
>
> ```
> function ScrollView({row}) {
>   const [isScrollingDown, setIsScrollingDown] = useState(false);
>   const [prevRow, setPrevRow] = useState(null);
>
>   if (row !== prevRow) {
>     // Row changed since last render. Update isScrollingDown.
>     setIsScrollingDown(prevRow !== null && row > prevRow);
>     setPrevRow(row);
>   }
>
>   return `Scrolling down: ${isScrollingDown}`;
> }
> ```

The reason the way you were doing it didn't work is that the value you pass `useState` is only used the **first** time the component function is called for a component, not every time it's called. On all subsequent calls, the state value stored for the component is used instead. That's the purpose of `useState`: To maintain state that changes during the lifetime of the component.

Here's an example showing how props can change after the component has been created, and how copying the prop to state via `useState` isn't correct (unless you want to remember the first-ever value of the prop):

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

const Example = ({propValue}) => {
    const [stateValue] = useState(propValue); // <== Usually not correct!
    
    console.log(`propValue = ${propValue}, stateValue = ${stateValue}`);
    
    return (
        <div>
            <div><code>propValue = {propValue}</code></div>
            <div><code>stateValue = {stateValue}</code></div>
        </div>
    );
};

const App = () => {
    const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        if (counter < 10) {
            setTimeout(() => {
                setCounter(c => c + 1);
            }, 800);
        }
    }, [counter]);
    
    return <Example propValue={counter} />;
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.12.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Notice how `stateValue` never increased, because once the initial value was used, the value from the React-managed state information for the component was used.

When your component instance is first created, it basically gets an array of slots, one for each hook it calls in the order they were called (that's why hook calls always have to be in the same order). The data from that array it filled in during your component function's first call, then reused each time the function is called to update the component instance. You can very loosely think of `useState` as following this pseudo-code:

```
function useState(initialValue) {
    if (componentState[hookIndex]) {
        return componentState[hookIndex];
    }
    return componentState[hookIndex] = [initialValue, createSetter(hookIndex)];
}
```

...where `componentState` is the array of component instance information, and `hookIndex` is the index of this hook call in the order of calls in your component function.

[This article](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/) by Dan Abramov is really helpful for understanding this stuff. It's ostensibly about `useEffect`, but really it explains how hooks work and the component lifecycle from a hooks perspective.

Comment: Excellent. I really appreciate the time you've taken to succinctly provide the solution to my problem and more importantly the WHY.

Comment: @Sash - My pleasure! :-)